# Trying to use Enum.reduce

Tags: enums, elixir

Trying to convert below template

```
[
  %{ids: ["A123"], name: "Red"},
  %{ids: ["A123"], name: "Blue"},
  %{ids: ["B123"], name: "Blue"}
]
```

to

```
[
  %{ids: ["A123"], name: "Red"},
  %{ids: ["A123", "B123"], name: "Blue"},
]
```

If the key name is same combine id in one list. For Eg: the name blue has two ids and merged t0 one list. Can anyone help me to achieve this using Enum.reduce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = [
  %{ids: ["A123"], name: "Red"},
  %{ids: ["A123"], name: "Blue"},
  %{ids: ["B123"], name: "Blue"}
]
```

Using [`Enum.group_by/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Enum.html#group_by/3) and [`List.flatten/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/List.html#flatten/1):

```
data
|> Enum.group_by(&(&1.name), &(&1.ids))
|> Enum.map(fn {color, ids} -> %{name: color, ids: List.flatten(ids)} end)
```

Using [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Enum.html#reduce/3) and [`Map.update/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Map.html#update/4):

```
data
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn %{ids: ids, name: name}, acc ->
  Map.update(acc, name, ids, fn prev_ids -> prev_ids ++ ids end)
end)
|> Enum.map(fn {color, ids} -> %{name: color, ids: ids} end)
```

As you can see using `group_by` is a little less verbose and possibly more clear. Both approaches use an intermediate map to make grouping easier.

Comment: For the 2nd one: `prev_ids ++ ids -- prev_ids` if you don't want to allow duplicate ids.